# drop_duplicates doesn't work on multiple identical rows instances

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to concatenate two Pandas DataFrames and then drop the duplicates, however, for some reason `drop_duplicates` doesn't work for most of the identical rows (only few of them dropped). For instance these two are identical (at least in my eyes) but they are still showing up: [Identical rows here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT8xb.png)

This is the code I have tried, the result with or without subset arguments varies but still doesn't give me the result I wanted. It tends to over delete and under delete when I play with arguments (for instance add or remove columns)

```
bigdata = pd.concat([df_q,df_q_temp]).drop_duplicates(subset=['Date', 'Value'], keep ='first').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Can anyone point me to a right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked that the values in the `'Date'` column are identical? Maybe they differ by a very small time amount? To answer questions like this it would always be helpful to get a sample of your actual data, rather than an image.

Comment: there can be many ways two "in appearance identical" rows are actually different. As @gofvonx says, it could be that the dates are slightly different; or it could be that some text values have difference in spaces or other hard-to-see diffs. Floating point values can also differ slightly and be displayed as identical, etc. To find out, take two rows you think are similar, and compare each values. That will give you ideas about how to normalize your data for more effective deduplication.

Comment: @gofvonx, thanks for your reply. Yes I did reformat date column down to seconds only after concatenation to make sure they follow the same format.

Comment: @PierreD, Awesome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, here is a way to make the differences explicit and normalize your `df` to drop near-duplicates:

### Part 1: show differences

```py
def eq_nan(a, b):
    return (a == b) | ((a != a) & (b != b))  # treat NaN as equal
```

Let's try with some data:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([
    ['foo\u00a0bar', 1, np.nan, None, 4.00000000001, pd.Timestamp('2021-01-01')],
    ['foo bar', 1, np.nan, None, 4, '2021-01-01 00:00:00']],
    columns=list('uvwxyz'),
)
df.loc[1, 'z'] = str(df.loc[1, 'z'])  # the init above converts the second date (str) as Timestamp
```

```py
>>> df.dtypes
u     object
v      int64
w    float64
x     object
y    float64
z     object
dtype: object
```

```py
>>> df.drop_duplicates()
         u  v   w     x    y                    z
0  foo bar  1 NaN  None  4.0  2021-01-01 00:00:00
1  foo bar  1 NaN  None  4.0  2021-01-01 00:00:00
```

Find what elements among those two rows are different:

```py
a = df.loc[0]
b = df.loc[1]
diff = ~eq_nan(a, b)
for (col, x), y in zip(a[diff].iteritems(), b[diff]):
    print(f'{col}:\t{x!r} != {y!r}')

# output:
u:  'foo\xa0bar' != 'foo bar'
y:  4.00000000001 != 4.0
z:  Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00') != '2021-01-01 00:00:00'
```

Side note: alternatively, if you have cells containing complex types, e.g. `list`, `dict`, etc., you may use `pytest` (outside of testing) to get some nice verbose explanation of exactly how the values differ:

```py
from _pytest.assertion.util import _compare_eq_verbose

for (col, x), y in zip(a[diff].iteritems(), b[diff]):
    da, db = _compare_eq_verbose(x, y)
    print(f'{col}:\t{da} != {db}')

# Output:
u:  +'foo\xa0bar' != -'foo bar'
y:  +4.00000000001 != -4.0
z:  +Timestamp('2021-01-01 00:00:00') != -'2021-01-01 00:00:00'
```

### Part 2: example of normalization to help drop duplicates

We use Pandas' own Series formatter to convert each row into a string representation:

```py
def normalize_row(r):
    vals = r.to_string(header=False, index=False, name=False).splitlines()
    vals = [
        ' '.join(s.strip().split())  # transform any whitespace (e.g. unicode non-breaking space) into ' '
        for s in vals
    ]
    return vals
```

Example for the first row above:

```py
>>> normalize_row(df.iloc[0])
['foo bar', '1', 'NaN', 'NaN', '4.0', '2021-01-01 00:00:00']
```

Usage to drop visually identical duplicates:

```py
newdf = df.loc[df.apply(normalize_row, axis=0).drop_duplicates().index]
>>> newdf
         u  v   w     x    y                    z
0  foo bar  1 NaN  None  4.0  2021-01-01 00:00:00
​
>>> newdf.dtypes
u     object
v      int64
w    float64
x     object
y    float64
z     object
dtype: object
```

Note: the rows that make it through this filter are copied exactly into `newdf` (not the string lists that were used for near-duplicate detection).

Answer (score 1):

**Take care of string columns with no values.**
Make sure in the dataframe the cells without value are read as `None`. Specially, in the `object` typed columns, there spaces with are different from `None`, but actually there is no value there.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col_1': ['one', ' ', 'two', None],
                   'Col_2': [1, 2, 3, 2],
                   'Col_3': ['one', None, 'two', ' ']})
df

    Col_1   Col_2   Col_3
0   one      1      one
1            2      None
2   two      3      two
3   None     2
```

As you see row 1 and row 3 don't have value in `Col_1` and `Col_2`. But, since two of them are `None` and the two others are spaces, they are different.

I had the same problem and struggled a lot with the code, since I found this. I solved it by replacing `None` values with spaces:

```
df = df.fillna(' ')
```